# Accessing all displayed strings in an apk

Tags: java, android

Is there a simple way to access all displayed text somewhere in an android app for manual translation? For example, on the opening screen, there could be 5 lines, and on particular button click, the next screen should come up. I have to access all the text of application in order to translate it.

Comment: have look this link..http://www.androhub.com/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, if the developer of the app followed a simple design guideline: Never use absolute String values, but create String **resources** instead.

A resource is simply a pair of key and value, for example it looks like this:

```
<string name="app_name"> EasyApp </string>
```

The key to access the resource is `app_name`. Now `app_name` can hold values for different translations. As you are working with Android Studio, I can recommend using the built-in [Translations Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor.html). It allows you to comfortably manage your translations of every key-value pair for each language.

Answer (score 0):

1. APK is merely a zip file.
2. You can just change its extension to zip and unzip it.
3. You will be able to find some XML files there in folders like `assets`, or `res` there.

Also there are some apps that can modify an application's string resources.